# regex find all words that contain at least one asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex pattern that matches all words containing at least one asterisk at any position in that word.

```
str = "t*e *pp locall* so my q**st*on is **stinct *ro* t*eir's. *ev***heles* lol ****"
```

should match

`t*e` `*pp` `locall*` so my `q**st*on` is `**stinct` `*ro*` `t*eir's`. `*ev***heles*` lol `****`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[\w-']*(?:\*+[\w-']*)+
```

- `[\w-']*` Match any word character, `-` or `'` any number of times
- `(?:\*+[\w-']*)+` Match the following one or more times

  - `\*+` Match `*` one or more times
  - `[\w-']*` Match any word character, `-` or `'` any number of times

```js
let s = `t*e *pp locall* so my q**st*on is **stinct *ro* t*eir's. *ev***heles* lol ****`
let r = /[\w-']*(?:\*+[\w-']*)+/g

while(m = r.exec(s)) {
  console.log(m[0])
}
```

Comment: impressive regex

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this?

```
/[^\s\.,?!]*\*+[^\s\.,?!]*/g
```

- `[^\s\.,?!]*` Match any character zero or more times that is not whitespace or punctuation.
- `\*+` Match `*` one or more times.
- `[^\s\.,?!]*` Continue to match characters until whitespace or punctuation is encountered, and terminate the match.

I threw in more punctuation since you seem to be wanting to omit that from matches:

```js
var str = "t*e *pp locall* so my q**st*on is **stinct *ro* t*eir's. *ev***heles* lol ****"
console.log(str.match(/[^\s\.,?!]*\*[^\s\.,?!]*/g))
```